# Using a splitter to use a washer and dryer on this outlet?

Tags: receptacle

I currently have 2 of these single outlets in my laundry room. I just had a tankless gas water heater installed that uses one of these plugs and I am currently left with just one plug for the washer and dryer. Can I use a plug splitter? I am electrically challenged...  [image]

It is a gas dryer, not sure if I can use a simple plug splitter from Home Depot to split that plug so I can plug both the washer and dryer into it. I am in Orange County California. It was built in the 90s I think...

Comment: Where are you located?  That is a 5-20R receptacle and normally on a 120V 20A circuit.  It's not enough electricity for a typical United States electric clothes dryer, which generally require a 240V 30A circuit (three times as much electricity.)  It sounds like the laundry room was setup for a gas dryer.  You're going to need another circuit for an electric one.

Comment: Is your dryer gas or electric?  Is getting a new dryer an option?

Comment: Since you had 2 I would guess you want another. Do you know if the water heater is on the same circuit? If this is a separate circuit from the water heater I would swap out this single with a duplex.

Comment: He has a gas tankless water heater so I’m guessing it’s a gas dryer too.

Answer (score 2):

What you showed us a picture of is a single receptacle.  (1-socket).

They make a very similar thing, which fits in the same space in the wall, which has 2 sockets instead of 1.

You can go ahead and swap that one for the 2-socket variety.  I would do it both locations so you have 4 sockets total.  That way you have a spare.

This is straightforward work for a handyman.  A proper electrician isn't even required.

Comment: If I did it myself, would I get a 20 amp duplex? Or does it even matter?

Comment: @Brian Yes, you would want to purchase a duplex 5-20R receptacle, if that's what you're asking. Turn off the breaker to the circuit, unscrew the cover plate & outlet, _take pics of the existing wiring_ (just in case), unscrew the wiring from the old receptacle and screw it onto the new one in exactly the same way. Rejoice with 2 outlets where you once had one.

Comment: @Brian what Freeman says, though you are also allowed to use the more common 15A duplex.